# Android GPS track locations to trigger event using Otto library

Tags: android, service, fragment, communication, otto

i want to use the GPS to track locations in the service,
once the device is close to some specific locations, post an event and the map fragment can do something based on the event. I thinking about using the Otto event library to do this,

But i am wondering if there is any other better ways to do this kind of communication between service and fragment?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I did the same, so, possible. It's straightforward as per their docs